# URL to Open Facebook Page with the UserID

Tags: facebook

I have the User Id of a Facebook user (UID).

I need the URL to use this ID to open their page.

I thought it was something like `www.facebook.com/**.php?UID=12345678`

Just putting in a number does not work, which I confirmed with my own UID.
(`www.facebook.com/12345678`)

Comment: I finally found the answer.  www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1234567

Comment: @Jason_93 feel free to add an answer to your question, maybe with a bit more detail if you have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxxxx

Comment: Poor Zoey Wen getting a lot of profile visits now...

Comment: That's funny.  It's x's now.